# SAS: how to make predictions using a range of pre-specified predictor values

Tags: sas, prediction, predict

I'm using `proc nlmixed` and [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/nlmixed_predict.htm) is an reproducible example.

```
proc nlmixed data="d:\data\hsb2";
   xb = b0 + b1*female + b2*write + b3*science;
   predict xb out=output1;
   model read ~ normal(xb,s2);
run;
```

`output1` contains the predictions based on `xb`. How would I obtain the predictions for females with writing scores 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and science score of 30? Essentially my predict data set would look something like this

```
  female writing science
1      1       0      30
2      1      10      30
3      1      20      30
4      1      30      30
5      1      40      30
6      1      50      30
```

How would I use the `predict` statement in `proc nlmixed` for making predictions on this set of pre-specified values?

Comment: Not an expert on `proc nlmixed` but it looks like you're going to run into problems because `read` is not on your input dataset. Do you get this error when you try running on your pre-specified values dataset?

Comment: You'll probably have to implement this yourself.  `predict` only works for in-sample observations and `proc score` only works for linear models.